# How can I log into a website using Python Requests when website has Jquery for login?

Tags: jquery, python, web-scraping, python-requests

I am trying to login to my clg website using a Python script
(Requests module) but I am unable to login. Can anyone please help me?
Note: I am a beginner in Python.

I am trying to login to this webpage(http://elab.krgi.in/elab)

Here is the code I am using:

```
import requests
with requests.Session() as c:
    page = c.get('http://elab.krgi.in/elab/login/student/home.php')
    print page.content
    url = 'http://elab.krgi.in/elab/index.php'
    USERNAME = 'uid'
    PASSWORD = 'password'
    c.get(url)
    phpssid = c.cookies['PHPSESSID']
    login_data = dict(username=USERNAME, password=PASSWORD)
    c.post(url, data=login_data)
    page = c.get('http://elab.krgi.in/elab/login/student/home.php')
    print page.content
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You need to use a tool like firebug or chromebug to trace the actual HTTP network calls and then transform these into the requests calls

Answer (score 0):

Since you did not mention any special errors besides: »doesn't work«, I had a look at how the JS did it:

```
var data = 'uname='+username.toString()+'&pass='+password.toString();
```

So, the Site is somehow expecting `uname` and `pass`.
You give `dict(username=USERNAME, password=PASSWORD)` which is in fact:
`{'username': 'bla', 'password': 'blabla'}`.

This could be one source of errors.